# How to propose a reworked pull request to a someone else's one?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Some time ago I contributed to a third party's repository on GitHub adding two new files to a repo.

So: forked the repo, cloned, modified, pushed and pull-requested.

Now another person has made a pull request to the same repository modifying my files and I am required to review those changes since I am those files' original author.

The PR is right about those files need to be updated, but it has been done the wrong way.

I'd like to make some changes starting from my original files - since some of the changes need to be reverted and others done in a different way - and then PR them, but I'd like my PR to be some kind of continuation to the other person's one.

Is there any way I can do that in a proper way? Or is the only way to create a totally new PR and comment on the previous PR to be closed and follow on mine?

Footnotes:

- Original PR is https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/9583
- Since I'm not the repo's owner, I don't have advanced privileges over it, I have just been asked to contribute on that PR. I also suppose I don't have special privileges over that PR.
- I have successfully checked out the PR as a local branch on my local repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question `A` is your repo and `B` is the other persons whereas `T` is the original repo.

From your post it looks like `B` has it the **wrong** way I would suggest you **comment on his PR** what is wrong and should be the right way to go about it. *It's a great way to learn for `B`*

If `B` has any valuable contribution and you have decided you will rewrite his wrong implementation proceed below else make your case to `T` or ask `B` with improvements edits on their side

1. Checkout a feature or point branch
2. Merge `B` on `A`'s new feature branch with a comment closes `B` PR #number. If it conflicts inform `B` you need a clean merge
3. Perform the reverts on commits you need to
4. Add your commits to the feature branch
5. Merge with the branch the PR was raise with and push to your remote

Your PR will contain his commits in the tree and once `T` merges it will close the original `PR` of `B`

Comment: That's it! Thank you!